# Knockout JS Observable Array visible Count

Tags: knockout.js

Using the Knockout JS set visible: data-binding on items in an observable array.  Is there a way I can get a count in Knockout JS of the number of items specifically with the visible data-binding = true?

I tried something like this (not working):

```
    var visibleItems = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.MyItems(), function(item) {
        return item.visible == true;
    });
    var result = visibleItems().length;
```

In this test, item.visible is undefined.  That's what I'm looking for, how can I get to Knockout JS' visible status property value that corresponds to their "data-bind=visible:"  Is that accessible somewhere within item?

Comment: Is `item.visible` an `observable` or just a regular property (i.e. do you need `item.visible() == true`)?

Comment: the code above isn't working, item.visible is undefined, that's what I'm really asking. In my html code, I'm saying data-bind="visible:blah".  How can I get to the knockout js "visible" property in my ko.computed observable?  Surely, it must be accessible somewhere in its API

Comment: Why are you trying to access the visible binding and not "blah", which you are binding to, and is presumably an observable property on one of your own javascript objects?

Comment: I'm trying to get the total count of visible objects.  I manipulate it with several different filters.

Comment: It sounds like it might be easier to have the `visibleItems` computed array on your root view model and bind to that, instead of showing all the items and setting the visible binding for each one.  Then its length will always match the number of items being displayed.

Comment: Yeah, I wish I could, that would be easier for getting a count, but I need to keep all the items in the array, because I'm using Node to push Real Time changes in.  Lots of magic going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless items in your observable array `self.MyItems` have a `visible` property, what you are trying to do cannot be done. The `visible` binding within Knockout changes the DOM element's `display` attribute rather than altering the underlying data.

From the documentation on the `visible` binding:

> - When the parameter resolves to a false-like value (e.g., the boolean value false, or the numeric value 0, or null, or undefined), the binding sets yourElement.style.display to none, causing it to be hidden. This takes priority over any display style you’ve defined using CSS.
> - When the parameter resolves to a true-like value (e.g., the boolean value true, or a non-null object or array), the binding removes the yourElement.style.display value, causing it to become visible.

Comment: The main view model property used for the visible: data-bind, is an observable tied to several other dependent observables.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly are you using with the visible data-binding? Is `visible` an observable property of the objects contained by `self.MyItems`?

Comment: Currently, the data-bind="visible:$root.IsThisVisible($data)" is to a view model method in the root.  Inside, IsThisVisible = function(data) { there are several dependent observable properties on the individual item that are properties inside the self.MyItems.  If any of the underlying dependent observables change, they can dynamically update the visibility of IsThisVisible().

Comment: Okay I see. Being that `$root.IsThisVisible` is not an observable, it makes sense that your UI would not update dynamically. I would recommend creating a `ko.computed` function for your items (represented in this case by `$data`) which returns `$root.IsThisVisible(self)`. This way, your items would have an observable property by which you can toggle their visibility.

Comment: Well, my UI is updating dynamically ok, based on the underlying dependent observables inside $root.IsThisVisible, the only problem, is getting the count of the visibles.

Comment: So you guys don't know of any way to get to the visible Boolean value in the back end object, that Knockout manages in the data-bind?  Thought that would be some kind of system property in Knockout.

Comment: It is not a system property in Knockout, as Knockout simply alters the DOM element's `display` attribute. You could select the DOM element using jQuery and access its display attribute, though. That would essentially give you direct access to the attribute which the Knockout `visible` binding toggles. It would be `$(element).attr('display')`, and if `display` is `none` then you know that the KO `visible` binding has hidden your DOM element.

Comment: Ok, I was able to get it to work by adding an additional IsItemVisible property to the viewmodel, updating it inside $root.IsThisVisible, and then getting the length inside a ko.computed with array filter like above, but using item.IsItemVisible() == true.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to use a ko.computed.  the reason being is that what you originally had would only get calculated once.

```
var visibleItems = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.MyItems(), function(item) {
        return item.visible == true;
    });
});

var result = visibleItems().length;
```

Comment: yeah, my code is inside a ko.computed, the .visible just isn't working for me

Comment: how are you determining that an item is visible?  what is the property that you are binding visible to?

Comment: I have several filters that determine visibility, but my question is trying to see if we can access knockout js' "visible" property that correlates to their data-bind="visible:" somehow inside the ko.computed. I have to imagine that's tracked somewhere. any ideas?